# Why am I getting a 404 error when I attemp to access my CodeIgniter app?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the [CodeIgniter manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) it demonstrates how to make a controller for blog.php.  It says you can point your browser at http://example.com/blog and it will display the echo "hello world"; code in the blog.php file in the controller folder:

When I go to example.com/blog I get a 404 error.  I removed the index.php in the url but I think this problem existed prior.

Any help would be great.

Comment: this is not a problem, this is default URL of CI.

Comment: I guess I am confused.  In the documentation it says that I can make a controller named blog.php and point my browser to it and have the controller echo "hello world"  I understand that its not its function but I just want to make sure it is setup properly.

Comment: @Schnaars: Can you successfully access yoursite.com/index.php/blog? Unless you use `mod_rewrite` and adjust your `config.php` settings, you must include `index.php` in the URL.

Comment: yes it is, you can even re-write the url as what you want

Comment: Are you literally accessing `example.com/blog`? Or `localhost/blog`? Because `example.com` is *an example*, you are meant to replace it with your own host name.

Comment: @colin: I did that yesterday.  I enabled mod_rewrite and adjusted config to remove the index.php however I believe that it was doing this prior.  I did a tutorial earlier that allowed me to create a little blogging system.  That required controllers and it seems to be working fine.  Is there something that I need to do in routes?

Comment: As a test, can you disable mod_rewrite, revert your config.php changes and then attempt to access `/index.php/blog/`? Also, be sure that you have a function within your Blog controller named `index` (since you're not specifying a function via the URL).

Comment: @meagar: its on my virtual host

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the blog route to the routes.php file?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Each URL needs to be mapped to a route so the framework knows which controller to run. It's simple to do, but unfortunately I haven't used CI for some time, and don't have any CI projects with me here to double check where to stick it.

However, the two video tutorials are very good and they'll get you going.

http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/

Have you had anything working with CI so far..?

Comment: -1 "Each URL needs to be mapped to a route so the framework knows which controller to run" is incorrect. You only need to add custom routes when you want to map to something different than the corresponding `controller/method/id` segments of the URL.

Comment: I stand corrected. I've obviously had my head in Symfony for too long.

Comment: Ok cool.  I am going to work on this.  Thanks for all your help.  Sorry for the newbie question.  I will report back when I get routes going.

Comment: @Schnaars: The point here is you shouldn't need routes for what you're trying to do.